# scanner input that can stop loop anytime?

Tags: java.util.scanner

I'm making a clock and I want a specific input to be able to stop it.
Any ideas?

Here's my code:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
  //...
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  //...  
  int s = 0;
  int m = 0;
  int h = 0;
  clock: // label to break a outer most loop 
  for(int i = 0; i<2; i++) {
    on = Boolean.parseBoolean(onValue[i]);
    while (on = true) {
      for (i=1;  i<=60; i++) {
        s++;
        if(input2check.compareTo("") == 0) {
          on = Boolean.parseBoolean(onValue[1]);
          break clock;
        }
        if (s == 60) {
          s = 0;
        }
        System.out.println(s + " sec" );
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: i believe some kind of 2 loops working in the same time, 1 listening got the scanner for user input and 1 working the loop, could that work? I don't know really how to do it...

Comment: This is a valid question that I want to know the answer of too. I will be giving this question a bounty.

Comment: I am unable to understand the question. You said you are making a clock so are you taking inputs from user to make it? Could you share an example in the case the clock needs to be stopped

Comment: @Aak, in my understanding.. he is trying to make a stopwatch that needs to be stopped. So.. the clock keeps running and whenever he wants to stop it, all he needs to input is a couple of words into console.

Answer (score 1):

***First idea: do the `Scanner` in a separate thread***

As you've noticed, `Scanner.nextLine` blocks until the user has input something and pressed Enter. We can ignore this problem if our clock does not run in the same thread as the `Scanner` loop. Let's use a daemon thread for reading user input.

*I've picked the word "off" as stopping input from the user.*

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Clock1 {
  
  private static volatile boolean on = true;

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    int s = 0, m = 0, h = 0;
    
    Thread t = new Thread(() -> {
      try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        while (on) {
          String input = scan.nextLine();
          if (input == null)
            continue;
          if ("off".equalsIgnoreCase(input.trim())) {
            on = false;
          }
        }
      }
    });
    t.setName("console");
    t.setDaemon(true);
    t.start();

    clock: for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) { //Why this loop ?
      long prevTime = System.nanoTime();
      long diff;
      while (on) {
        if (++s % 60 == 0) {
          s = 0;
          if (++m % 60 == 0) {
            m = 0;
            ++h;
          }
        }
        do {
          diff = System.nanoTime() - prevTime;
          Thread.sleep(Math.min(1000 - diff / 1_000_000L, 100));
        } while (on && diff < 1_000_000_000L);
        if (!on)
          break clock;
        prevTime = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println(String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", h, m, s));
      }
    }
    
    System.out.println("Clock stopped");

  }

}
```

You need to be aware that timing a clock with `Thread.sleep` is inaccurate, though. But it may be enough for your problem...

I tried to compensate for this using several checks for `System.nanoTime` per second, but accurate timing would require a more complex algorithm. It also allows for about immediate reaction to user input.

***Second idea: use a `BufferedReader` rather than a `Scanner`***

Using a `BufferedReader` allows us to avoid blocking execution while we check if the buffer is ready, and then only read user input when they've pressed Enter, thus bypassing the problem with `Scanner.nextLine`.

```java
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class Clock2 {

  private static volatile boolean on = true;

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException {

    int s = 0, m = 0, h = 0;

    try (BufferedReader rdr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in, StandardCharsets.UTF_8))) {

      clock: for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) { // Why this loop ?
        long prevTime = System.nanoTime();
        long diff;
        while (on) {
          if (++s % 60 == 0) {
            s = 0;
            if (++m % 60 == 0) {
              m = 0;
              ++h;
            }
          }
          do {
            diff = System.nanoTime() - prevTime;
            Thread.sleep(Math.min(1000 - diff / 1_000_000L, 100));
            String line;
            while (on && rdr.ready() && (line = rdr.readLine()) != null) {
              if (line.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("off"))
                on = false;
            }
          } while (on && diff < 1_000_000_000L);
          if (!on)
            break clock;
          prevTime = System.nanoTime();
          System.out.println(String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", h, m, s));
        }
      }

    }

    System.out.println("Clock stopped");

  }

}
```

***Third idea: use a ScheduledExecutor***

This time, the clock is timed by a `ScheduledExecutor` that executes the increment loop once per second in a separate thread as the main program.

Accumulated values had to be stored in a class, so I also implemented `AutoCloseable` with class `Clock3` to ease shutting down the executor when the clock stops.

User input is read in a loop in the main thread using a `Scanner` until we hit the word "off".

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Clock3 implements AutoCloseable {
  
  private static volatile boolean on = true;

  private ScheduledExecutorService exec = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
  private int s = 0, m = 0, h = 0;

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    try (Clock3 clock = new Clock3()) {
      
      try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        
        while (on) {
          String input = scan.nextLine();
          if (input == null)
            continue;
          if ("off".equalsIgnoreCase(input.trim())) {
            on = false;
          }
        }
        
      }
      
    }

    System.out.println("Clock stopped");

  }
  
  public Clock3() {
    exec.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
      if (++s % 60 == 0) {
        s = 0;
        if (++m % 60 == 0) {
          m = 0;
          ++h;
        }
      }
      if (on)
        System.out.println(String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", h, m, s));
    }, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }

  @Override
  public void close() throws Exception {
    exec.shutdownNow();
  }
  
}
```

I don't know how accurate this scheduling is guaranteed to be. From what I can read from documentation for `ScheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate`:

> If any execution of this task takes longer than its period, then subsequent executions may start late.

Which will never be the case with this small increment algorithm.

There are probably better ways of scheduling that however, but that was not the point of your question...

Comment: There was a small mistake in my calculations with nanoseconds, that was not noticeable due to the min function. Corrected now. Thanks for accepting my answer BTW :)